# Would it be a RedHat permission issue for a executable jar to get an SSLHandshakeException between servers?

Tags: java, ssl, https, redhat, executable-jar

Troubleshooting someone elses problem over the phone.

The error is trying to connect from one server to another servers db over ssl.
The error message is: 'requires a valid client certificate'
I've done everything to ensure that they have created the correct cert.
I had them debug=yes ssl:handshake and send me the logs.
In their logs they have nothing set for the keystore and the wrong path for the truststore.

Herein I think lies the issue. We have an executable jar that reads the paths and passwords for the keystore/truststore and sets the values via calls such as `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", config.getKeyStore());`
from within the executable. I've verified at least locally that I can communicate over SSL from 1 server to anothers database in our test environment and all is fine. If I were to remove all of the settings then the error log generated by the ssl:handshake gives me the 'requires a valid client certificate'.

- I'm told that the destination server with the DB has its pg_hba file
  set properly to accept the communication over SSL from the specified
  id.
- I've verified that the cert is valid from the CA.

The only thing that I can think of is that the executable jar is not setting the values to the System via the code System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");

Is this a configuration that needs to occur to the Red Hat server to allow the jar to set system properties or is this at the file permission level or ? ? ?

I'm at a loss here and would appreciate any guidance on this issue.

Very difficult environment. I'm on the North-East tasked to assist someone in Midwest to trouble shoot them trying to connect to our Database in the South-West. I have no access to the actual servers and have to try and debug over the phone.

Comment: There is no OS-level permission for the JAR to set system properties, but your JVM settings/startup script/parameters might be setting a security manager that prohibits it.

Comment: Could you tell me what the JVM script file might be called and or where it is located?

Comment: I don't use red hat but there might be a policy file somewhere in the account's home folder. The start-up script is part of your application, if you have one.

Comment: Are you trying to do 1-way (server certificate only) or 2-way SSL (server and client certificates)?

Comment: I believe we are only doing 1 way. What I have been told is that the server *A* is trying to run the executable jar which in turn calls the database over SSL on server *B*. I don't have direct access to any of the systems so I have to try and help over the phone. I'm no SA. However what I have noticed from the log file they sent me after trying to execute the jar with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake I can see that there is no *keystore* specified whereas in my local environment that I am using to test things I can see my keystore. Also their truststore points to an incorrect location as well.

Comment: Are you sure or can you/they check that `config.getKeyStore()` etc is actually returning the correct values on the target system? Are you sure `setProperty` for `javax.net.*` are executed *before the first* SSL/TLS connection, or more exactly the first use of the default factory? In other words, is there any configuration or environment that might cause database access to occur earlier in the startup sequence on their system than on yours, or faster if multithreaded?

Comment: I have been trying to get a hold of the person for the past 2 days to check on what is being returned. As for looking at their code, the configurations are read in and then calls are made to set them via `System.setProperty`. After this is when a db connection is attempted to be made. On the database server logs from what I had been told, there is no sign of any attempts to connect.

Comment: I just learned last night that they are using the default Java that comes with RedHat. Is it possible that this is the issue? I don't want to be messing with the /lib/security/java.policy and or java.security settings on their system because as far as I can tell on our system we never had to alter those files in order to get the code to work here.

Comment: This is still an open issue. Unable to determine why we are only able to execute this via a full call on the command line and not through the .jar using `System.setProperty()`